How do I resolve "no parser for 'vimdoc' language" (or clean my installation)?
I am new to Neovim and decided to install the kickstart.nvim config.
After using it for a while I didn't like it, so I tried to remove it. Something went wrong in this process: after deleting most of the files of the configuration, I keep receiving this error when I try go to :help treesitter or open a .lua file.
Error detected while processing BufReadPost Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35: Error executing lua: /usr/share/nvim
/runtime/filetype.lua:36: BufReadPost Autocommands for "*"..FileType Autocommands for "*"..function <SNR>1_
LoadFTPlugin[20]..script /usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/help.lua: Vim(runtime):E5113: Error while calling
 lua chunk: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:107: no parser for 'vimdoc' language, s
ee :help treesitter-parsers
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/language.lua:107: in function 'add'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/languagetree.lua:111: in function 'new'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:41: in function '_create_parser'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:108: in function 'get_parser'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter.lua:416: in function 'start'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/ftplugin/help.lua:2: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:36: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35>
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:36: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35>
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:35: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>

I uninstalled Neovim, removed all cache files, and re-installed, but nothing works.
Im using Fedora 40 and Neovim v0.10.0.
Running :TSUpdate didn't work because the command doesn't exist.
The result of :verbose autocmd BufReadPost is below
--- Autocomandos ---
filetypedetect  BufReadPost
    *         <Lua 25: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
        Definido pela última vez em Lua (run Nvim with -V1 for more details)
              if !did_filetype() && expand('<amatch>') !~ g:ft_ignore_pat | runtime! scripts.vim | endif
        Definido pela última vez em Lua (run Nvim with -V1 for more details)
gzip  BufReadPost
    *.gz      call gzip#read("gzip -dn")
        Definido pela última vez em /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim line 25
    *.bz2     call gzip#read("bzip2 -d")
        Definido pela última vez em /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim line 26
    *.Z       call gzip#read("uncompress")
        Definido pela última vez em /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim line 27
    *.lzma    call gzip#read("lzma -d")
        Definido pela última vez em /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim line 28
    *.xz      call gzip#read("xz -d")
        Definido pela última vez em /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim line 29
    *.lz      call gzip#read("lzip -d")
        Definido pela última vez em /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim line 30
    *.zst     call gzip#read("zstd -d --rm")
        Definido pela última vez em /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim line 31
    *.br      call gzip#read("brotli -d --rm")
        Definido pela última vez em /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim line 32
    *.lzo     call gzip#read("lzop -d -U")
        Definido pela última vez em /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim line 33
editorconfig  BufReadPost
    *         <Lua 29: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/plugin/editorconfig.lua:4>
        Definido pela última vez em Lua (run Nvim with -V1 for more details)


Could you share with us the result of the Neovim command: :verbose autocmd BufReadPost?

It seems that treesitter fails to get some of its language parser I would also try to run the :TSUpdate Neovim command.

@VivianDeSmedt thanks for your attention, i edited the post with the results

I don't recall how Fedora's yum works, but after uninstalling Neovim, make sure you purge any files left over in /usr/share/nvim and ~/.config/nvim or any other stdpath location that could be part of the problem.  (This is another reason not to use framework-style installations: they are too hard to debug.)

@D.BenKnoble t r u e

Do not post answers in the body of a question: write a self-answer instead. I’ve removed your edit. Note that you should include links to the GitHub conversation or elsewhere that might be relevant and summarize their content.
